# How to setup child routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to figure out how child routes in VueJS work. I would think that if I had a news overview with links to each news item, I could then use a child route to view the news item, but it doesn't works as I expects.

Is it me that is doing it wrong or?

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
    {
      path: '/news',
      name: 'news',
      component: News,
      children: [
        {
          path: ':id',
          name: 'newsitem',
          component: Newsitem
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

[I have created a jsfiddle to show how I would expect it to work.](https://jsfiddle.net/v28yw3g5/)

If I uncomment the router in the javascript, then it works fine, but not with children.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Moersing.Lin said you forgot to put a `<router-view>` in your News Component.

Here is an working example of your fiddle:

```js
const News = {
  template: `<div>
<h1>News</h1>
<br><br>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
`
}
const Newsitem = {
  template: "<h2>News {{this.$route.params.id}}</h2>"
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/news',
    name: 'news',
    component: News,
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      name: 'newsitem',
      component: Newsitem,
    }]
  }]
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'news'}">News list</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'newsitem', params: { id: 'item-1' }}">Item 1</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'newsitem', params: { id: 'item-2' }}">Item 2</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Moersing.Lin talked about a `<view-router>`

Answer (score 4):

I got it, A Vue Router is required `<router-view></router-view>`,but in your code, The `root` component is there, but you forgot the `parent`,it needs a `<router-view></router-view>` too.

https://jsfiddle.net/v28yw3g5/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const News = {
  template: `<div>
<h1>News</h1>
<br><br>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
`
}
const Newsitem = {
  template: "<h2>News {{this.$route.params.id}}</h2>"
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/news',
    name: 'news',
    component: News,
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      name: 'newsitem',
      component: Newsitem,
    }]
  }]
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'news'}">News list</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'newsitem', params: { id: 'item-1' }}">Item 1</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'newsitem', params: { id: 'item-2' }}">Item 2</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```